# Is it necessary to synchronize .NET SerialPort writes/reads?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

In my application I use the .NET SerialPort class for reading and writing data. The reading is done using the DataReceived event, I assume internally on a ThreadPool thread. The writing is done by the UI thread (WinForms).

I was wondering, if it's necessary to synchronize the access to the SerialPort instance, so that no Reads/Writes can happen at the same time. My conscience tells me I should put locks around these calls, but I'm puzzled as all C# SerialPort examples I find on the Internet don't use locking at all.

Comment: You should definitely lock. Most likely, the examples you find on the Internet are oversimplified. I try to make it a rule to read the documentation carefully for any example I'm trying to follow, just in case something like this has been omitted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a great thread on the topic, with the author of the SerialPort class participating:

[MSDN: How does SerialPort handle DataReceived?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/e36193cd-a708-42b3-86b7-adff82b19e5e/)

From my experience, I've written a dozen serial communication apps for use as hardware simulators, I don't lock.  I didn't know at the time if I was safe or not, but in practice, I haven't had an error yet. (a year of near constant use by 20+ testers and automated test machines)  That said, my applications don't leave the company, if I were writing apps for public consumption I might take more care.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent and informative link—that's a nice find. But I think one should take caution not to rely too much on these kinds of implementation details when making design decisions like the original question poses. It's interesting and good to know exactly how things work under the hood, but given it's not officially documented, there's no guarantee it will stay that way. The documentation (and best practice) recommends that you lock, so that's what I'd do unless there's a particular *disadvantage* to doing so.

Comment: Wow, that link definitely answers some questions! I will go with locks, as I also will have to handle such scenarios as closing and reconnecting the serial port using the same member reference in my class, so those things will have to be synchronized too

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation:

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type (SerialPort) are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

So you should definetly synchronize your read/writes with locks.

Comment: Yes I know that wording, that's why I was going to synchronize those calls in the first place.